# need...twitter, facebook, other share buttons with counters

Tags: twitter, facebook, fbml, fbjs

I need 3 share buttons for my web page... like this plz check

http://www.start-vpn.com/category/vpn-offers/?type=0&orderby=meta_value_number&key=hits&order=desc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search and you will find.

e.g. http://developers.facebook.com/